# Add a "on behalf of ..." line to the author field in an article

Tags: titles, authblk

I'm writing a conference proceeding using the standard `article` class.

To typeset authors and their affiliation I'm using the [authblk](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/authblk.html) package, and I'm really satisfied with it.

However, the people writing the paper are a subset of a larger team, so, after the authors' names, I'd like to display a line saying *on behalf of NameOfTheTeam* (and only then the affiliation).

As an example:

[image]

How can I achieve it? Should I modify the `\maketitle` macro? Or something inside the authblk package?

Comment: Put this information in the acknowledgements.

Comment: Despite providing an answer, I agree with Charles.

Comment: In this case, team policies matter more than LaTeX :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather patch the  `authblk` package that you are using as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\makeatletter
\usepackage{authblk}

\def\@author{}
\renewcommand\@author{\ifx\AB@affillist\AB@empty\AB@author\else
      \ifnum\value{affil}>\value{Maxaffil}\def\rlap##1{##1}%
    \AB@authlist \\*[0.3cm]On behalf of a great Team!\\[\affilsep]\AB@affillist
    \else  \AB@authors\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\title{Brief Article}
\author[1]{author1}
\author[1]{author2}
\affil[1]{Institute of Nowhere}
\author[2]{author3}
\affil[2]{Institute of Somewhere}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Adjust spacing etc to suit!

Comment: Great! Look like what I wanted :) I wonder if there is a way to add a command to the package that do the same.

Comment: @Alessandro You can do that, but I would rather keep it in the preable, that way if there is an update of the original package you do not lose your revision.

Comment: In fact, I already put a modified copy of the package in my local tree, so any update (despite the fact that the last version is dated 2001) wouldn't be lost :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}

\newcommand*\andnewline{%
        \end{tabular}
        \\[\bigskipamount]
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
}
\title{Paper Title}
\author{Author \#1\textsuperscript{2,5} \and
        Author \#2\textsuperscript{2,4} \and
        Author \#3\textsuperscript{2}   \and
        Author \#4\textsuperscript{2}   \and
        Author \#5\textsuperscript{1,3,5}\andnewline
  on behalf of the Biggest Team Ever\andnewline
        \textsuperscript{1}Affiliation \#1; \and
        \textsuperscript{2}Affiliation \#2; \and
        \textsuperscript{3}Affiliation \#3; \and
        \textsuperscript{4}Affiliation \#4; \and
        \textsuperscript{5}Affiliation \#5}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The `geometry` package is just to get all of the authors fitting on a single line. To be clear, this isn't necessary, and a 0 pt margin shouldn't be used. I used it to distinguish my answer from Herbert's which relied on having exactly one author wrap to the next line.

Comment: using `\\[\bigskipamount]` is word like ... and `margin=0pt` not realistic ...

Comment: @Herbert: The geometry package isn't required at all. It was just to show that it wasn't relying on having the final author (and only the final author) wrap the way yours was. I also got the `\bigskipamount` from your solution...

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Paper Title}
\author{Author \#1\textsuperscript{2,5} \and
        Author \#2\textsuperscript{2,4} \and
        Author \#3\textsuperscript{2}   \and
        Author \#4\textsuperscript{2}   \and
        Author \#5\textsuperscript{1,3,5}\\[\bigskipamount]
  on behalf of the Biggest Team Ever\\[1cm]~}
\date{\textsuperscript{1}Affiliation \#1; 
      \textsuperscript{2}Affiliation \#2;
      \textsuperscript{3}Affiliation \#3;
      \textsuperscript{4}Affiliation \#4;
      \textsuperscript{5}Affiliation \#5}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\date` for that seems very wrong.

Comment: It also only works because Author 5 gets pushed to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Would a solution involving the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package and redefining the `\maketitlehookb` (or whichever) work?